# Second command does not execute array.map

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, arguments, notation

I have this code below and my last elsif statement has two commands. issue is when I run the code, only the first command executes.

For example, if I run translate("banana"), it returns bananabay, correctly adding "#{x[0]}ay" to array banana however, the second command, which is deleting x[0] does not execute and I got bananabay as the return instead of ananabay which is expected.

what do you think is happening?

Code here:

```
def translate(word)
  vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
  consonants = ["b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"]

  word = word.split

  word.map{ |x|
    if vowels.include? x[0]
      x=x << "ay"
    elsif consonants.include? x[0] && x[1]
      "#{x[2..-1]}#{x[0]}#{x[1]}ay"
    elsif consonants.include? x[0]
      x = x << "#{x[0]}ay"
      x.delete(x[0])
      x
    end 
  }.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is coming back unchanged is because `#delete` does not alter the original input when called - it returns a new string reflecting the result.

To remedy this, you can either call `#delete!`, which would modify the string in place, or you can assign the result of your delete method back to `x`:

```
x = x.delete(x[0])
```

However, this will remove *all* instances of `x[0]` from your string (e.g "banana" would become "ananaay") - I don't think that's what you want your function to do.

If you wish to remove only the first instance of the target letter, you can call `#sub`, like so:

```
x = x.sub(x[0], "")
```

Hope this helps!